# Can't retrieve a particular attribute from WebElement

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to retrieve the id from the below given HTML using selenium.

```
<tr ..">
<td><input type="checkbox" id="chkTES_0" class="shftchkbox" data-id="-997278">&nbsp;<span id="spTESCt_0" class="tesCount" data-key="3023005" title="This Test Execution Spec is not added yet">0</span></td>
<td ...></td></tr>
```

I tried using `element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"td")[0].get_attribute("id")`
However it gives empty string. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that that is the very first table data element on the page? It may be finding another one if there are more.

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure it is the first one. This is because when I do .get_atrribute('innerHTML'), it gives the correct values inside it.

Comment: findElements would return a list of WebElements, you need to iterate over this list and call `.getAttribute('id')` on individual Webelement

Comment: Please post the script you are using for this, as well as the URL you're trying to retrieve the element from as part of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per *HTML* you have shared, to extract the value of `id` attribute e.g. **chkTES_0** from the `<input>` tag you can use the following line of code:

```
inputTagID = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td//input[@class='shftchkbox' and @type='checkbox']").get_attribute("id")
```